# the opposite of choose

Tags: combinations

I remember some of my math related to combinations, and that if I have 6 objects and want to count the number of pairs that I can make from these it is 6 choose 2 which equals 15.

However, now I know that I have 15 pairs and I want to know how many unique objects I need to make these pairs?

Is there a formula for this?

thanks

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you're asking to solve

$$\binom{n}{2}=k$$

but

$$\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

so

$$n^2 -n-2k=0$$

and

$$n=\frac{1 + \sqrt{1+8k}}{2}$$

Comment: I'll leave you to worry about when $1+4k$ is an odd square, I don't feel it's what you wanted to hear here

Comment: Hmmmm, $\sqrt{61}$ is not quite integer... You should change $\sqrt{1+4k}$ to $\sqrt{1+8k}$...

Comment: You are indeed right, thanks

Comment: great thanks!  I guess I could have worked that out.

Comment: Yeah, just try to not think of factorials as anything mysterious